# how to tokenize a c program if the data types are like unsigned long int etc

Tags: c, token

My problem is given below - 
Write a program which gets in input, a program (from a file) and prints all variables in it as output.

Ex. Inputprogram.txt

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c=10;
    char p, *ptr=NULL;
    unsigned long long int t;
}
```

Output must contain: a,b,c,p,ptr,t.

My program is -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int isDataType(char buffer[]){
  char types[19][10] = {"char","const","double","float","int","long","register","short","signed",
"static","struct","union","unsigned","void","volatile","int*","char*","float*","enum"};

  int i, flag = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < 19; ++i){
    if(strcmp(types[i], buffer) == 0){
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  return flag;
}

int main(){
  char ch, buffer[15], operators[] = "+-*/%=.#";
  FILE *fp;
  int i,j=0;

  fp = fopen("inputprogram.txt","r");

  if(fp == NULL){
    printf("error while opening the file\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
      if(ch == operators[i])
        printf("%c is an operator\n", ch);
    } 

    if(isalpha(ch)){
      buffer[j++] = ch;
    }

    else if((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == ',' || (isdigit(ch))== 1) && (j != 0)){
      buffer[j] = '\0';
      j = 0;

      if(isDataType(buffer) == 1)
        printf("%s is a data type\n", buffer);

      else  
        printf("%s is a variable\n", buffer);
    }

  }

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

This code is not giving desired result if the data like `unsigned long long int` comes in the txt file.
How to optimize the code in such a way that if the data types like `unsigned long int` or `int *` (int space star) comes then also it is able to print the exact variable.

Comment: `int *` should be considered two different tokens IMO. And for e.g. `unsigned long long` you need to have a context-aware tokenizer.

Comment: If you need to cover all cases, this is quite a hard problem. You almost need a full c syntax parser. Think of cases like "int" (in a string), typedefs, etc. pp.

Comment: Today's homework in C beginner class: create a C compiler. Hmm.

Comment: Go back a step and make your code classify each token cos currently it doesn't handle the function declaration

Comment: Is this a programming exercise or part of a project? If it is a project, I would recommend letting a compiler help as much possible. `gcc` with `-fdump-tree-all` provides some processed files which may be easier to parse than the original `c` file. If it is an exercise, then it is very difficult to solve completely.

Comment: Its a programming exercise

Comment: Kindly help. I tried to get line by line from the file and used strtok but not able to proceed further as to where to bifurcate the string.